# forcing VLC to play h264 video file

Tags: video, filenames, h.264, vlc

I have an h264 video file without video container information, but I am using only a 8.3 FAT File system.
When opening a *.h264 file with VLC, VLC plays it correctly since it understands that this is an h264 encoded video.
But how can this be done if I am only able to have 8.3 format for filenames?
How can I tell VLC that a file named X.264 for example is an h264 video file?
Windows Media Player 10 and above is able to identify this automatically.
Thanks,
Avi Tal.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you just use the extension .mkv? Not sure if VLC is smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: file.264 works on most players.

Comment: See RBT solution below. VLC does not recognize it unless --demux h264 is used

Comment: @AviTal Apparently VLC does not play files ending with .h264 without that, as well.

Answer (score 10):

I usually use this command to play raw `h.264` from my MAC.

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC ~/Movies/demo.264 --demux h264
```

Note that you have to invoke it from terminal.

Hope it answer your question.

Comment: THANKS! Works perfectly!

Comment: This worked for me whenever a particular MacOS installation of VLC would not play files with the .h264 extension as well.  Nice to know about these command-line workarounds. I knew VLC had played my network video recorder's files with the .h264 extension in the past on the same Mac before I wiped it for repair; after that a fresh installation of VLC did not. I ran the above command on, say, file.h264 and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

This also works if you find .mp4 files won't play (and you know they were encoded with H264). In those circumstances the prompt is "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC ~/Movies/demo.mp4 --demux h264"